# Retrieve value of field in list of entity objects by its ID field

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I have something like:

```
List<Cat> cats = AnimalEdmContext.Current.Cats.ToList();
```

Where `Cat` is a table in my database, with fields `CatId` and `Breed`.
How can I access the value of the `Breed` field that corresponds to a given integer `CatId`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to query over the database to do that. The following example shows you how to do that.

```
var theCatId = 1; // Or whatever
var theCatIWant = AnimalEdmContext.Current.Cats.Where(c => c.CatId = theCatId).Single();
var theBreedIs = theCatIWant.Breed;
```

Doing this you just retrieve from the database the Cats that match your condition. In the other hand, if you do the filtering over the whole list like the one you are getting in your question, you will be retrieving all records from database and then filtering them, which costs more.

The Single LINQ method allows you to specify the condition as well, that the single element should match. I have added the Where method to so it is clearer what we are doing.

Single will throw an exception if no record is found or if more than one are found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ::

var catBreed = cats.First(x=>x.CatdId == desiredId).Breed;

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a specific item, you could do something like:

```
var cat = AnimalEdmContext.Current.Cats.First(cat => cat.CatId == 1);
var breed = cat.Breed;
```

This will retrieve the first Cat item in the table that has the ID of 1, in this example.